# "bash: command not found" using while loop to perform arithmetic operation in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to read each line of a file "certtemp1.txt" using while loop in bash. The file "certtemp1.txt"contains some numbers for example such as below.

```
5000
6000
7000
```

I am trying to deduct each number in the file one by one from 8000 to get output. Below is my script and the error.

```
$currentEpochTime=8000

while read i; do $(( i -  currentEpochTime )): done < certtemp1.txt
```

The output gives me correct answers but with some errors as below

```
bash: 3000: command not found
bash: 2000: command not found
bash: 1000: command not found
```

I tried to look at lot of articles, but does not resolve my error in output

Comment: I would use `awk` for this, something like `awk '{print $0  - 8000}' certtemp1.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just need to print those numbers.

Currently what happens is that your script does go through all the file and subtracts `8000` from the number on each line. But it doesn't print the result. Instead it executes the result.

All you need to do is add an `echo`.

```
while read i; do echo $(( i -  currentEpochTime )); done < certtemp1.txt
```

Should do the job.

Comment: Thanks Mihir. just adding the echo works. Much appreciate your prompt answer

Answer (score 0):

Put "echo " in front of your $((...)).  Your syntax performs the arithmetic and then tries to execute it.

```
#!/bin/bash

currentEpochTime=8000

while read i
do
    echo $(( i -  currentEpochTime ))
done < certtemp1.txt
```

The result is:

```
-3000    
-2000    
-1000
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard Jessop. putting `echo` before command does work. @Mihir had suggested the same earlier